# Method that plots i all the x values to a given math function

Tags: python

Hey i need help with programing a method that plots i all the x values to a given math function

```
def compute(expression):  #The expression is where the math function is gonna be placed
    print("Evaluerer", expression)

    for i in range(0,1001):
        x=i/100.0 #This is all the x-values, which needs to be put into the expression
```

Thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

Define your function :

```
def f(x):
    return x #put here your expression of f(x)
```

Then plot your function as follow:

```
plt.plot([i/100.0 for i in range(0,1001)], map(lambda x: f(x),[i/100.0 for i in range(0,1001)]))
```